# Google api AndroidPublisher InAppProduct update returns Internal Server Error 500

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client

While developing in Java with AndroidPublisher I'm trying to update an InAppProduct object.
first of all I get the object using:

```
AndroidPublisher.Inappproducts.Get get = 
inappproducts.get(packageName, skuName);
InAppProduct inAppProduct = get.execute();
```

then i manipulate it according to my logic
and try to update the object using:

```
AndroidPublisher.Inappproducts.Update update = 
inappproducts.update(packageName,skuName,inAppProduct);

update.execute();
```

and I receive the following error message:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 
500 Internal Server Error
{
"code" : 500,
"message" : null
}
```

any ideas why is this happening? and how can I solve it?

Comment: "Internal Server Error"  is just a server hiccup as far as I have found.  your best bet is to catch it and try and run the request again.

Comment: I've tried over and over, don't think is a simple temporary server hiccup.